# Ubuntu 21.04 - Keyboard backlight problem after suspend/wake up

Tags: suspend, asus, keyboard-backlight

I have the [Asus ROG Zephyrus 2021 version G14 (GA401QE)](https://rog.asus.com/laptops/rog-zephyrus/2021-rog-zephyrus-g14-series/) which I received FreeDOS and using it dual boot with Windows 10 installed first and then Ubuntu 21.04 with kernel 5.13.4.

I had trouble with WIFI card (Mediatek mt7921), but manually updating kernel version to **5.13.4 (on linux git, it states that it is fixed 5.12+ )** solved it. So no problem there now and everything works great except the minor problem with keyboard backlight.

Basically the problem is, when waking up from sleep, keyboard backlight just stays in breathing mode (as if it is still in sleep) and no way to turn it off or even adjust the brightness.
Normally, when in sleep, backlight is in breathing mode. After waking up it just stays like that and no way to control it, which makes me think that backlight control is not "waking up".

It is just stuck in that mode until restarting the PC.
It is a minor thing, but it bothers me a lot.

I also came across similar things, but those are related to booting and not being able to control <kbd>Fn</kbd> key etc. About `/etc/systemed/`
I don't know if anyone came across a similar problem.

Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered in [Redit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ASUS/comments/op1i6o/comment/h7u7oqz/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) so I'm complementing that.
You need to install [asusctl](https://gitlab.com/asus-linux/asusctl) from their GitLab repository and then use the command `asusctl led-mode static` to change the keyboard LED mode.

According to [asusctl](https://gitlab.com/asus-linux/asusctl) documentation at least kernel version 5.15 is required, but I installed this in Kubuntu 21.10 with default 5.13 kernel. Just followed the instructions in the repsitory:

```
# Clone and install dependencies
git clone https://gitlab.com/asus-linux/asusctl.git; cd asusctl
apt install libclang-dev libudev-dev
# Install Rust
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
# Build and install
make
sudo make install
# Start service
systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart asusd
```

Run `asusctl --help` to check other options and features.